# fgets does not trigger

Tags: c, fgets

fgets gets skipped when i run my code.
the scanf lines work just fine.

Here is the relevant code from a header file:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED16_FUNCTIONS_H
#define UNTITLED16_FUNCTIONS_H

struct student{

    int studentID;
    char studentName[100];
    int age;
}student_t;

void get_information(){
    printf("Type your student ID: ");
    scanf("%i", &student_t.studentID);

    printf("\nType your name: ");
    fgets(student_t.studentName, 100, stdin);

    printf("\nType your age: ");
    scanf("%i", &student_t.age);
}

void print_information(){

    printf("Student id: %i\n", student_t.studentID);
    printf("Name: %s\n", student_t.studentName);
    printf("Age: %i\n", student_t.age);
}

#endif //UNTITLED16_FUNCTIONS_H
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't mix `scanf` with `fgets`

Comment: so i should use fgets for the others also?

Comment: You can use `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()` to the string. Or other functions such as `strtol()` etc.

Comment: the general recommendation is to avoid `scanf` when possible.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't disagree, but you're fighting a losing battle.  There's a neverending stream of new learners out there, and every single one of them is using a textbook or tutorial, or listening to an instructor or a YouTube video, inducing them to use `scanf`.  And none of those textbooks, tutorials, instructors, or videos are offering the slightest hints about using `scanf` safely: not mixing it with `fgets` or `getchar`, checking the return value, putting a space before `%c`, not trying to read multiple things on one line, etc., etc., etc...

Comment: @SteveSummit Well, saving a single soul still worth it, no? :)

Comment: it cirtanly is for me, thank you for the clarification ;)